# Deformed model after rigging

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I'm new to Blender and 3D modeling altogether.
Right now I'm working on my first fully rigged, low poly character, after rigging and weight-painting I found that my character became somewhat deformed, I have not posed the character in any way. Does anybody know how to solve this?

Normal Character in Edit mode
[image: Normal Character]

Deformed Character in object mode
[image: DEFORMED CHARACTER]

Comment: do you have IKs or other constraints?

Comment: Have you tried resetting the transform? (Alt+G, Alt+R, Alt+S)

Or have you used X mirror while weight painting? This could cause problems if your mesh is off centre or the geometry is non-symmetrical. Also have you checked your vertex groups? Perhaps you've painted some vertices you shuldn't have during weight painting. Try unassigning vertices from vertex groups where they shouldn't be in edit mode.

Comment: maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @HenrikD Yes I have IK:s, not sure if I need them, but the tutorial I went trough while rigging my character used them.

Comment: Disable the IKs and see if that makes the problem disappear. If so, go through the IK settings

Comment: Thanks @MarkJackson but resetting doesn't seem to be working and i did not use mirror while weight painting.